# Angular Routing Issue After Deployment

Tags: angular, angular-routing

So, I created a website using Angular 6 and deployed it on github.
This project uses Routing to redirect the user directly to '/home' page rather than to load '/' page.
link to the project is : [here is the project link](http://tanaytoshniwal.com).
The Issue is, when I first load the site, the routing works perfectly and redirects to '/home' page
whereas if i directly open the '/home' page,
it shows an error.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: use historyApiFallback

Comment: Its because / is loaded first in your angular app, and I guess then it redirects to /home.

If you do /home directly, then the route isn't picked up by angular because first / loads and then the internal router for angular goes to /home.

Comment: How to use historyApiFallback with Angular 6? @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala

Comment: @TaranjitKang so what should i do to fix this issue?

Comment: you got a guide in the first comment linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Github hosting, we need to explicitly create another file named "404.html", exactly same as index.html.
That solved the issue